# Need a top down menu button example for metadata Navigation

Tags: sharepoint-server, managed-metadata, managed-navigation

Ive created a metadata based Managed Navigation in sharepoint 2013 on premises . Everything seems to work fine but in places where the submenu is larger the menu exits the screen height giving a vertical scroll (See Image Attached).
[image]
    Need a chrome settings like top and down buttons to navigate through the longer menu. (Also see attached image)

[image]